# Events not rendered on the grid

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I've added fullcalendar to my project however for some reason it does not display the events with in the day grid

I've tried changing the timezone, a combination of times and dates all the same.

// Html

```
      <full-calendar  #calendar
                    defaultView="dayGridMonth"
                    selectable="true"
                    (eventClick)="handleEventClick($event)"
                    [header]="{
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
  }"
                    (dateClick)="handleDateClick($event)"
                    [eventSources]="eventSources"
                    [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
                    [weekends]="calendarWeekends"
                   ></full-calendar>
```

// Component

```
      calendarVisible = true;


       calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin, timeGrigPlugin, interactionPlugin];
          calendarWeekends = true;


      eventSources: [

        // your event

 source
    {
      events: [ // put the array in the `events` property
        {
          title  : 'event1',
          start  : '2019-10-01'
        },
        {
          title  : 'event2',
          start  : '2019-10-05',
          end    : '2019-10-07'
        },
        {
          title  : 'test',
          start  : '2019-10-12T12:30:00',
        }
      ],
      color: 'black',     // an option!
      textColor: 'yellow' // an option!
    }

    // any other event sources...

  ]
```

Example i am following: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-array[image]

Also using Angular 8 with FullCalendar 4.3.1 in Chrome

Comment: Please add your code so we can check the issue. It would be better to have jsfiddle

Comment: or a stackBlitz is even better. By the way are you using Angular or AngularJS?

Comment: Angular and AngularJS are two different frameworks and have different change detection strategies. Without any code, the question can't be tagged properly and there is no specific answer.

Comment: Added to question - Most of my code is application specific.

Comment: I upvoted just to keep your points even now that you have fixed the question.

Comment: @AaronBedward You know I was thinking of something your events are supposed to be in 2010 but you've posted a picture of 2019.Maybe you could check if it appears in 2010?

Comment: Sorry i reverted my code and added the wrong eventsource - updated

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
  eventSources:any = [
{
  events: [ // put the array in the `events` property
    {
      title  : 'event1',
      start  : '2010-01-01'
    },
    {
      title  : 'event2',
      start  : '2010-01-05',
      end    : '2010-01-07'
    },
    {
      title  : 'test',
      start  : '2010-10-12T12:30:00',
    }
  ],
  color: 'black',     // an option!
  textColor: 'yellow' // an option!
}
]
```

see the [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullcalendar-angular-demo-mjeq1x?file=src/app/app.component.html)

also in your post you are showing a screenshot of 2019 and your events are in 2010.

based on this declaration you could also write

```
[events]="eventSources[0].events"
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue appeared to me when some css was not imported/bundled/added correctly.

Adding

```
@import '~@fullcalendar/common/main.css';
@import '~@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
@import '~@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css';
```

to the top of the stylesheet styling my calendar fixed it.

Disclaimer: I do not know much about web development, so this might be a bad solution.